# ICL, OS X.4/5 and Unix compliance ($UNIX2003)

Tags: macos, unix, intel, standards-compliance

I'm trying to compile a Mac version of our lib for a customer that wants to include it in a Photoshop plugin, and he is having trouble linking our lib into his app. More detailed info: His plugin is built against the CS4 Photoshop SDK, which means the Mac OS base SDK should be 10.4. My lib is a static one, compiled with the Intel compiler 11.1 and the base SDK is also set as 10.4.

I tested my lib against a small test app I wrote, and it compiles and works fine (on 10.5). To replicate my customer's environment, the app is compiled with gcc, and uses the 10.4 base SDK. While its fine for me, my customer cannot manage to link with my lib. The problem is the following: Undefined symbols:
  "_fputs$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      _write_message in libMyLib.a(libm_error.o)

When I compile my lib with gcc,and all other project settings the same, its fine, he can generate an executable. As soon as I compile with ICL, it breaks down. Could it be that ICL 11.1 is not compatible with 10.4? On the Fortran compiler forum, I found the following answer:"From the output provided it appears Xcode defaulted to Mac OS X 10.4, which the 11.1 compilers do not support."  (http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/68647/)
Does that mean ICL 11.1 does not run on 10.4, or that the code it generates doesn't work on 10.4??

On the following page (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-compatibility-of-intel-compiler-for-mac-os-x-and-xcode/), it also says that ICL 11.1 is not compatible with 10.4 (again same question: what does compatibility mean?). However, it says that ICL 10.1 is, so I tried. But now, even my own test app does not link, for the same reason (undefined function$UNIX2003).

Does anybody know what is the problem, and how to fix it? Or a way to work around it?

Thanks in advance,

A

PS: bonus point if somebody knows what this one means:
ld: absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) used in _Cholesky from libMyLib.a(Cholesky.o) not allowed in slidable image. Use '-read_only_relocs suppress' to enable text relocs

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is: compile with ICL 10.1, not 11.1. None of the Intel libs used by 10.1 contain references to $UNIX2003 routines.

Hope it helps somebody.

A

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you're going to need to get Intel product support from Intel, but if you want to sell Mac software that actually works then you should probably just use the same toolchain as everyone else and forget about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But using Intel means a 4X increase in performance. Worth the pain if you ask me.

Comment: Seems like it means a 100% decrease in performance if it doesn't work.